# How to query buyer orders from database to their profile

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to query buyer orders from database to their profile(dashboard), so when a buyer place order he should see the order information in his dashboard.

My code isn't working well, how do I fix this.

Controller

```
 public function myOrders(User $user)
 { 
 $orders=Order::where('buyer_id',$user->id)->get();
  return view('myOrders', compact('user','orders'));
  //dd($orders);
 }
```

Blade view

```
   @foreach($orders as $sell) 
  <tr>
    <td>{{$sell->orders}}</td>
    <td>{{$sell->products}}</td>
    <td>{{$sell->created_at}}</td>
    <td>{{$sell->order->shipping_name}}</td>
    <td>{{$sell->order->shipping_city}}</td>
    <td>{{$sell->order->shipping_phone}}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="">View Order Details</a>
    </td>
 </tr>
 @endforeach
```

User.php

```
 public function orders()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(Order::class, Products_model::class, 'buyer_id', 'seller_id', 'product_id');
}

public function orderFromBuyers()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough(OrderProduct::class, Products_model::class, 'buyer_id', 'product_id');
}

public function orderFromSellers()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(OrderProduct::class, Products_model::class, 'seller_id', 'product_id');
}
```

OrderProduct.php

```
 <?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class OrderProduct extends Model
{
protected $table = 'order_product';
protected $fillable = ['order_id', 'buyer_id', 'seller_id','product_id', 'quantity'];

public function products()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Products_model');
 }

public function buyer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'buyer_id');
}

public function seller()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'seller_id');
}

public function order()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
 }
 }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is not working for you?

Comment: @AngadDubey my controller isn't working it shows this error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'buyer_id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Can you share your ERD for these tables (users, productModels, orders)

Comment: @AngadDubey here is my database tables https://imgur.com/a/Ud9e2Hh

Comment: Have you tried `$orders = $user->orders()->get()` ?

Comment: Yeah am getting this `Unknown column 'products.buyer_id'`

Comment: your orders table does not have a buyer_id field.

Comment: @BenSholdice yeah but it is in OrderProduct table, I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: include your complete OrderProduct model - is it a pivot? also include your order model. you will need to query using your eloquent relationship. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations.

Comment: I have update my complete OrderProduct model @BenSholdice

Comment: your hasManyThrough relationship is bad. `User` has no relationship with `Product` through `Order`. The `Order` model needs a `Product` foreign_key. I suggest you re-work your schema like the example here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: @BenSholdice i have order_product table which has product id, order_id, buyer_id etc here is how it looks like https://imgur.com/V4qX2KH